# An alternative, algebraic way to introduce interactions. Are there other ways out there?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, research-level

An opening paragraph:

> The usual approach to introducing interactions in quantum field theory
>   is to make the constraint on the
>   amplitude of the field towards smaller
>   values more forceful than harmonic.
>   For example, instead of the massive
>   Klein-Gordon field's harmonic
>   constraint towards smaller field
>   values,
>   $\partial_\mu\partial^\mu\phi(x)+m^2\phi(x)=0$, we introduce a more forceful
>   constraint,
>   $\partial_\mu\partial^\mu\phi(x)+\lambda_1\phi(x)+\lambda_3\phi(x)^3=0$.
>   We require $\lambda_3>0$; $\lambda_1$
>   may be tuned so that a non-zero value
>   of $\phi(x)$ is preferred, if
>   $\lambda_1<0$. Here, we instead
>   introduce a constraint on the observed
>   field by an alternative, algebraic
>   method. We take the observed field to
>   be a bounded function of the field,
>   $\Phi(x)=\mathsf{gd}(\phi(x))$, where
>   the Gudermannian,
>   $$\mathsf{gd}(z)=2\tan{\!{}^{-1}\!\left(e^z\right)}-\frac{\pi}{2}=\tan{\!{}^{-1}\!\left(\sinh{z}\right)},$$
>   amongst other possible definitions, is
>   complex analytic for $z\not=(2n+1)\pi i$ and has bounded real component
>   between $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and
>   $\frac{\pi}{2}$. The use of the
>   Gudermannian is inessential to the
>   development, but we will use it as a
>   convenient explicit mapping of the
>   infinite range of measurement values
>   of a free (quantum) field
>   $\hat\phi(x)$ into a bounded range of
>   measurement values
>   $\mathsf{gd}(\hat\phi(x))$, with which
>   we can make some analytic progress. In
>   the usual terms of a potential energy,
>   this construction effectively imposes
>   an infinite potential on the field
>   outside the range
>   $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$,
>   because field values outside this
>   range cannot occur, while preserving
>   an attractive harmonic potential when
>   the field is close to zero. It seems
>   possible that the process of
>   renormalization in the context of
>   Hamiltonian or Lagrangian formalisms,
>   by infinite adjustments of parameters,
>   effectively constructs a potential
>   that is comparable to this analytic
>   ideal.

My doubts about this paragraph are a little worrying. It emerged from the mathematics that I've been pursuing for the last two months, building on other mathematics that goes back about a year. I'm quite embedded in a way of thinking that is somewhat different from most peoples' conventional. When in this state, something like the above always looks *convincing* to me —I discover six months later why it's not, but right now I'm rather (too) pleased with what you see above. I'm asking here (1) whether people see the paragraph above as plausible enough at least to withhold judgment until they see the Math, or even that it seems enticing; or (2) that it looks hopeless (hopefully including some hint as to why, of course); and (3) whether there's anything that this reminds you of [Citations welcome, in the Math or Physics literature]. Answers that let me shortcut around that six month wait to seeing why this can't work will be welcome.

I guess this is, as the sidebar recommends, "sharing my research", though I don't want to take the space to "provide details" beyond a certain point. I'm curious whether it's an effective question. In formulating this question around the above paragraph, it occurs to me to clarify that I'm unhappy with deformation of a Hamiltonian or Lagrangian formulation of a quantum field as the only way we have to construct a new quantum field, particularly because of renormalization, and I'm also unhappy with the nonconstructive tendency in axiomatic quantum field theory. I don't see anything else in the literature, but is there?

EDIT: Luboš rightly focuses on the unlikeliness of the Gudermannian as a preferred choice of transform. As little as possible should depend on the choice of field coordinatization. The working abstract I have calls it a toy model, which I would hope would bring the comment above into focus, that

> "The use of the Gudermannian is inessential to the development".

Nonetheless, the Gudermannian is mathematically useful in the QFT context I am developing (1) because it has poles only on the imaginary axis, so just two series expansions are enough to evaluate it, effectively around $\pm\infty$, which is of course possible only because the Gudermannian is finite at $\pm\infty$. This makes analysis considerably more manageable. [Explicitly, we can express $\mathsf{gd}(z)=\mp 2\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty(-1)^j\frac{1-e^{\pm(2j+1)z}}{2j+1}$ for $\Re(z)<0$ and $\Re(z)>0$.]

(2) Using $\mathsf{gd}$ instead of $\arctan{}$ is also useful for analysis, because the exponential of the quantum field acts as a displacement operator instead of as a derivation. [Explicitly, $[a(x),f(a^\dagger(y))]=f\mathbf{\,'}(a^\dagger)C(x-y)$, where $[a(x),a^\dagger(y)]=C(x-y)$ is the commutator, acts as a derivation, whereas $e^{\alpha a(x)}f(a^\dagger(y))=f(a^\dagger(y)+\alpha C(x-y))e^{\alpha a(x)}$ acts as a displacement operator.]

(3) $\tanh{}$ is a superficially simpler choice, but it's significantly less convergent. [Explicitly, we have to expand the denominator of $\frac{-1+e^{2z}}{1+e^{2z}}$.] $\mathsf{gd}$ is the simplest bounded function that satisfies these three criteria. I so far can't think of a way to get all this into an opening paragraph, unless there is a precedent I don't know of that sets up a context that is close enough to what I'm doing.

I find even the little I can do with this toy model gives *a little* insight into renormalization, though it's certainly allusive. There is a chaotic regime at time-like separation, for example. Perhaps I have to get into the paragraph above that the move to analysis might be worth trying just because perturbation theory is a non-convergent expansion. I'm already seeing things slightly different because of your comments. Many thanks.

EDIT(2): Luboš asks for clarification of the general idea. At the moment I'm trying to see ways to combine multiple heterodox ways of constructing models. To me, the Hilbert space structure is paramount because it underlies any probability interpretation; positivity of the energy is less important than it is usually taken to be, because it is neither necessary or sufficient to ensure stability; a continuous mass spectrum arises in the Källén-Lehmann representation of the 2-point function of a renormalized theory, so it should not be ruled out as part of other types of models; field renormalization suggests some kind of transformation of the unbounded quantum field to bounded values. Latterly, I've thought that a more analytic approach to models would be better than the series expansions that are universally used. In a few weeks or years I may have dropped any or all of these constituents of the models I have been constructing and characterizing. The published papers that are referred to on my web-site gives some idea of the different kinds of heterodox models I've constructed, understood at some level, and dismissed in the past.

There is an answer, by the way, to the question "Are there other ways out there?", which I came across only a few days ago. [Detlev Buchholz, Gandalf Lechner, Stephen J. Summers, "Warped Convolutions, Rieffel Deformations and the Construction of Quantum Field Theories"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00220-010-1137-1). This and its references claim to construct an interacting QFT in 3+1 in the Haag-Kastler axiomatic context, although I'm just now making my way through it.

Comment: I don't understand why this is an alternative way to introduce interactions. You're just guessing a potential for a scalar field in a theory - your theory because this random function is almost certainly not a potential in any theory we care about (why it should be?). And the only special feature of this function is that it is bounded. Well, it's pretty normal for realistic potentials e.g. in string theory to converge to a constant when the potential is sent to $\pm\infty$. The dilaton is a typical example.

Comment: However, in a theory with gravity, it's questionable what a "constant potential" is because one may always change the units - the "frame" - by redefining the metric by a multiplicative function of the dilaton (or other similar scalar fields). But in a general (effective) field theory, it's surely the case that one may add rather general potentials of scalar fields to the Lagrangian, although they're unlikely to be a randomly guessed function, and these potentials may also be viewed as results of resummations including loops.

Comment: I will probably think of why this comment is obviously inappropriate later, but a first thought is about that Gudermannian transform (which I hadnt heard of before). It looks a little bit like a Conformal Transformation (of the $\phi$ field). If so then there is potential here (in several senses).

Comment: @Roy @Luboš is right that picking off the Gudermannian as special is not a good idea as Physics. The working abstract I have calls it a Toy Model. I've added a clarification in the Question, although what should go into an effective first paragraph currently eludes me.

Comment: @Luboš Thanks for your comments. I've added an EDIT that explains what I find mathematically special about the Gudermannian, while I certainly admit that it may not even be as much as a starting point for other approximations. In terms of potentials, I think of this as going to infinity at constant field, rather than to a constant at infinite field. Thanks for citing the dilaton, which I will have to think about.

Comment: Thanks for your update, Peter. You've added new ideas - but you just divided my puzzle into two parts: I still don't understand why the poles should only be strictly along the imaginary axis; and even the space of functions with poles along the imaginary axis is infinite-dimensional, so one still doesn't know what should be special about this particular one. It may be a toy model - something you decide to solve to gain some expertise or general ideas - but in that case, I still haven't understood what these general ideas are.

Comment: @Luboš Thanks! The poles being on a line, with the function invariant under translation by $2\pi i$, is only a matter of practicality for a toy model, not of principle, for the reason (1) that I give in my first EDIT. What my general ideas are is harder. One motivation would be that I want to do renormalization in a different way, which I take to push me towards algebraic methods, but I want to keep some contact with engineering practicality, not do LQP. I see a (weak) link between the construction above and field renormalization, because it transforms infinite field values into finite values.

Comment: @Peter: can you expand a bit your comments about the Buchholz-Lechner-Summers? I'm not sure whether we're both make the same reading of that paper.

Comment: @Daniel I haven't yet got far enough into the paper to do more than cite the claim on the second page, "It provides the first fully consistent examples of relativistic quantum field theories on four–dimensional Minkowski space describing nontrivial elastic scattering processes". I don't yet see them making contact with practical QFT (I suppose a "no long-range correlations" restriction will appear or be implicit), but I've always supposed that twisted algebraic structures of some kind *might* be another way. I also just noticed the "elastic", though this might not be too big a restriction.

Comment: As far as I know the models in 3+1 dimensions constructed by deformation are all just wedge local. While in 1+1 dimension Lechner etablished also locality for double cones for certain classes of models with factorizing S-matrix.

Comment: You are not introducing interactions, you are reparametrizing a field.